# How can I increase the length of a python list based on a parameter?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My question is related to the increase of a python list length with the use of the parameter. Specifically, I have the following lists:

```
l1 = list(range(10))
l2 = [False for i in range(10)]
```

I can merge them into a list of dictionaries by implementing the following code:

```
res = [{l1[i]: l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))}]
```

The result is the following:

```
[{0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False}]
```

I would like to repeat the content of the dictionary `x` times. For example, if `x=2` the `res` list would be the following:

```
[{0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False},
 {0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False}]
```

My question is:
How can I repeat the content of the dictionary based on the `x` number and save the result on the `res` list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to join your 2 lists together, then repeat them with another list comprehension:

```
l1, l2 = [*range(10)], [False]*10
x = 3
res = [dict(zip(l1,l2)) for _ in range(x)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just expand your comprehension by another loop like this:

```
N=3
res = [{l1[i]: l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))} for _ in range(N)]
print(res)
```

```
[{0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False},
 {0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False},
 {0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: False,
  5: False,
  6: False,
  7: False,
  8: False,
  9: False}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = [dict(zip(l1, l2)) for _ in range(x)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res = [{l1[i]: l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))}] * x
```

Comment: Don't do that. All dicts in your list will be just a reference to the same object. If you do `res[0][0] = True`, all dicts will get this change.

Comment: Yes I see. Do you have any suggestion for overcoming this issue? @Rodrigo Rodrigues

Comment: Yes: don't use the `*` operator to construct an array if the elements are reference types (like `dict`, `list`, `set`...). Use a comprehension instead: `[dict() for _ in range(x)]`

Answer (score -1):

You can multiply a list.

```
res = [{i: False for i in range(10)}] * x
```

Comment: Don't do that. All dicts in your list will be just a reference to the same object. If you do `res[0][0] = True`, all dicts will get this change.